# Beginning of the week / end of the week

Tags: word-choice

It is possible to say:

三月初 (the beginning of March)
三月底 (the end of March)

Example：

我三月底要回国

You can also refer to:

年初 and 年底

But is there something you can use to convey the beginning or end of the week, for example "I am going to my parents house at the end of next week"?

Comment: Now that's an interesting question - looking forward to the answer to this one. Thanks for getting my brain juices flowing ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 周末 zhōu mò : The weekend
>
> 周初 zhōu chū : The beginning of a week

Note:

1. In general, 周末 refers to Saturday and/or Sunday clearly, while 周初 is a little ambiguous. 初 means "the beginning", and 周初 could refer to Monday or Tuesday or even Wednesday. You could say “星期三左右" to mean "days around Wednesday". ”左右"(zuǒ  yòu) means "approximate,around, about".
2. You could say “月末(=月底),年末(=年底=岁末),周末,期末(qī mò,= the last few days of a semester in school)",but don't say "期底" or "周底" or"岁底". That sounds wierd.

Answer (score 3):

`周末` is used for weekend (the end of the week)

`星期一` (Monday) is usually referred to as the beginning of the week.

"I am going to my parents house at the end of next week?" can be translated as `下周末我去我父母家`